# Network Interface Lost Functionality after Firewall Installation Hung

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I tried to install Agnitum Outpost firewall, but the setup hung while installing network drivers.

Oddly, the NIC properties shows no connect string whatsoever, nor any services...Device Manager shows problematic drivers as well.

Any suggestions?

Using Windows XP SP3.

PS2: I applied instructions below, but all were in vein:

> http://www.agnitum.com/support/kb/article.PHP?id=1000041
>   http://www.agnitum.com/support/kb/article.PHP?id=1000159

Answer (score 0):

Go back to a previous system restore point.

See [Restoring Windows XP to a previous State](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial56.html#restore).

Comment: Unfortunately, I've turned off System Restore altogether. 

Any other way to reinstall network functionality?

Comment: @Sadeq: Ouch, you should have never done that. Can you delete these funny devices in Device Manager?

Comment: Well, I did that due to lack of space. I managed to delete those devices by searching "Afw" in the registry, and deleting the relevant keys (as per http://www.agnitum.com/support/kb/article.php?id=1000041), but the problem does not go away.

Comment: @Sadeq: Try to delete the NIC in Device Manager and reboot to re-install it. But first turn on System Restore and create a restore point.